# How to combine apple script with bash script

Tags: bash, applescript

I am trying to combine applescript with bash script but its not working for some reason. Can someone correct my syntax error please? (when executing its saying `line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file` there is no line 18??)

```
  2 #!/bin/sh
  3 declare -a sites
  4 sites=("www.google.com")
  5 for site in "${sites[@]}"; do
  6     if ! wget "$site" --timeout 1 -O - 2> /dev/null | grep "server down" then
  7         echo "The site is down"
  8
  9 osascript <<EOF
  10 tell application "Google Chrome" to tell the tab of its window
  11     reload
  12 end tell
  13 EOF
  14
  15
  16    fi
  17 done
```

So the aim is to look for a site, grep a specific message if true reload google chrome.

UPDATE:
So I manage to get it to implement the appscript with a function but its keep spiting out echo connected even if the site is down. This is updated code:

```
 2 #!/bin/sh
 3
 4 function ex_app_scpt () {
 5 `osascript <<-AppleScript
 6 tell application "Google Chrome" to tell the tab of its window
 7     reload
 8 end tell
 9 return quit
 10 AppleScript`
 11 }
 12
 13 declare -a sites
 14 
 15
 16     if  [ /usr/bin/wget "www.google.com" --timeout 1 -O - 2> /dev/null | grep "server down" ]; then
 17         echo "The site is down"
 18         ex_app_scpt
 19     else
 20         echo "connected"
 21     fi
```

Any reason why?

Comment: a semicolon is missing before `then`

Comment: BTW, running this through http://shellcheck.net/ would probably have spotted it without getting humans involved.

Comment: If i do 'grep "server down"; then' it still errors with 'syntax error: unexpected end of file'

Comment: you must not use brackets here the command is wget, also the 2>/dev/null  redirection masks errors

Comment: when [] removed it still moved to echo "connected". Could i have a example on your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The error message may be due to the semicolon missing before then.

The interpreter doesn't recognize then as a keyword but as an argument.

With bash the error message is more clear because when it fails encountering `fi` keyword.

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```